# How to create an sh script to run another sh script with Screen session or Tmux session

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gnu-screen

All I want is create a bash script that runs another bash script in a different folder, but with a detached screen session. Also it should be executed as non-root user. Here's what I've done:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
cd /bot/ && screen -S Bot -d -m ./bot.sh
chmod +x script.sh
```

After running it with `./script.sh`, it doesn't give me an error, but no response.

Also I tried with:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
screen -S Bot -d -m -c "cd bot" && ./bot.sh
```

And come up with this error:
`./script.sh: line 1: bot.sh: No such file or directory`

I've a little question too: how can I make a script to track on this session to run it back if session or bot terminates?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want/need this? Tell us what you really want, and we may be able to come up with a much better solution than what you currently think is the solution to your problem.

Comment: Hello, i think the problem solved with Tmux script. And you're right, i should have told clearly what i want. I want this script works on startup with non-root user, but also have ability to restart on session or bot itself terminates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script is based on a number of presumptions:

1. I'm using tmux instead of screen
2. The script you want to run inside tmux is `/bot/bot.sh`

So the `./script.sh` I would suggest is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
sessname="Bot"

# Create a new session named "$sessname"
tmux new-session -d -s "$sessname"

# Run command in the session "$sessname"
tmux send-keys -t "$sessname" "/bot/bot.sh" Enter

# Attach to the session "$sessname"
#tmux attach -t "$sessname"
```

A couple of remarks:

1. You should always use absolute paths in a script (`/bot/bot.sh`, not `./bot.sh`)
2. If you also want to attach to the session, uncomment the last line

Comment: So much thank you for your interest. Could you helping with making this script to run at startup with non-root user and find a way to keep eye on it to restart when it terminates?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your first option works fine, but `screen` will run in detached mode, so you'll see no output outside `screen`.

Check `screen -ls` to see running `screen` sessions and `screen -r ID` to attach to them.

Anyways, you could better use absolute paths: `/bot/bot.sh` instead of `cd /bot/ && ./bot.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
screen -S Bot -d -m /bot/bot.sh
```

You should be able to attach to the `screen` with `screen -r Bot`.

---

Your second script is quite wrong:

```
screen -S Bot -d -m -c "cd bot" && ./bot.sh
```

- `-c` would expect a file:

  > `-c file`
  > override the default configuration file from "$HOME/.screenrc" to file.
- It runs `./bot.sh` outside the session because `&&` will separate your commands. So, you're still in your initial directory where `bot.sh` does not exist. Hence the error.